# Has anyone ever used Snapchat's camera kit in your web app?

Tags: reactjs, snapchat

I've used snapchats camera kit and filters in my react web app according to this https://docs.snap.com/camera-kit/quick-start/integrate-sdk/integrate-sdk-web/web-configuration#playback documentation but can't find anything about recording a video. How do i record a video ?